How to compare the disk size and the database size in Zabbix?
I am going through scenario where the Postgresql database is growing very fast and it could rich the whole disk space.
So I suppose there is a possibility to use a Zabbix trigger to compare those two parameters and send an alert.
I found some advice here https://www.zabbix.com/forum/zabbix-help/5898-can-i-directly-compare-2-items-values-in-a-trigger but it is unclear how to apply it.
Is it posible to do at all?
